# Binding animation duration to slider

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, animation, data-binding

On My **MainPage** I have

```
<DoubleAnimation Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed_1" 
            Storyboard.TargetName="factImage"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.3"
            AutoReverse="False"/>
```

Instead of hardcoding *Duration="0:0:0.3"* , I want to bind it to a slider on **Setting** page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewModel which is used by both pages.

For example, you can have a ViewModel with a `Duration` property which is set by the `Settings` page via binding, but is then binded to  your animation in `MaingPage` too.